# Composite primary key or guid for merging databases

Tags: database-design, relational-database, replication

I have scenario like this:

I have many machines and there is database on each. There is also one client machine that can pull data from all machines and add to his local database (it could have data from previous download). So tables on `many' databases need some unique identifier.

`many` - databases on each machine

`merged` - database on client machine that pull data from `many` databases.

My two ideas:

1. `GUID` primary key in `many` databases and also `GUID` in merged database.
   Here I also need column id of machine to distinguish rows between machines.
2. integer primary keys in `many` databases and composite key in merged one (GUID id of machine+integer primary key from `many` databases)

   Here I assume that each of `many` databases don't need GUID for itself, but only for `merged` one, so GUID is only needed in `merged` and it is a composite key.

What is better choice for this scenario? Maybe I miss something.

Comment: It is not clear if these are _existing_ databases and you need to consolidate them or if you are designing for a disconnected system. Please expand on the requirements.

Comment: Your edit hasn't clarified things for me.

Comment: I'am now designing that databases.

Answer (score 0):

`GUID` is ideal for such a system - it practically ensures that no primary key collisions will occur. Since you are designing it, you can use GUIDs as temporary identifiers in your `many` databases and replace them with integer keys in the `merged` one.

Another option is to partition the ID's between the `many` databases, so each can only use a range of IDs that non of the others can use. This is not trivial to do well (i.e. without having an estimate of how long these databases can exist without resync you may "overflow", you need to be able to offer additional ranges once a database "runs out" etc...) and may not suit your particular needs.